# Webdriver action wrapper/method

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given:

```
elem = driver.find_element(:css => ......)
@driver.action.click(elem).perform
```

Is it possible to drop the `@driver` line in the method and have something like:

```
Ruby.rb
def self.actionclick
 @driver.action.click(VARIABLE).perform
end
```

So in scripts, I would use something like `Ruby.actionclick(VARIABLE)`.

This will help as not to type the whole line `(@driver.action.click(elem).perform)` everytime.

Comment: How often do you really use actions? Do you have a good IDE? If so, it makes things like this easier. I would take care not to wrapper simple things like this because it makes your code harder to follow. Anyone with Ruby/Selenium is going to know what `@driver.action.click(elem).perform` does... no one but you is going to know what `Ruby.actionclick(VARIABLE)` does.. and why would you `actionclick` a `Ruby`?

Comment: @JeffC I am trying to get Chrome working as well not just FF and this is the only way I was able to get this to work. I will actually will be using quite often and that's why decided to find easy way. I use RubyMine as my IDE